# MySQL table Management for User with different UserId

Tags: android, mysql, json, servlets

I'm developing an android application which is for online data store. Now what I'm facing difficulty. First thing is I have Single table in database MySQL for various Users for registration. And another table for saving notes of users. But the problem what I am facing is

I want to retrieve specific notes for specific user than what I have to do for that purpose.

**Things what I'm facing are:**

1. I don't know to retrieve specific notes from the table of notes for specific users.
2. I am retrieving notes from table of notes, but for each user log in, user will get all the notes and not specific notes which he/she saved.
3. I am using J SON for parsing data. And database is MySQL/Servlet.

Answer (score 0):

(can't comment because of reputation)

**Do you have a foreign key in your notes table?**

If you have a primary key for your user table you can set that as your foreign key for the notes table and then use a select statement to select notes where `user.primarykey = notes.foreignkey`

Comment: I have tbl_user and user_id is the primary key for that table. And tbl_notes table for notes.. now how can connect these two tables by query??

Comment: alter table tbl_notes add column user_id int(20)(**Use whatever character set you made for the user_id in the user table, not int(20)**) not null;     Then make it a foreign key:  Alter table tbl_notes add constraint fk_notes foreign_key(user_id) references tbl_user(user_id) on delete cascade on update cascade;